# _setting.scss file to import not found or unreadable in Foundation 6

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, gulp-sass, zurb-foundation-6

I've installed foundation 6 through foundation cli, and chose zurb-template. Everything is working ok when I run

```
foundation watch
```

From this moment, any file I change in src folder produces the reloading of the browser.
The problem arises when I change anything in my own _settings.scss.

The error message I get is:

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    src\assets\scss\app.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: settings
       Parent style sheet: 
D:/wamp64/www/investoo_frontend2/src/assets/scss/app.scss
        on line 3 of src/assets/scss/app.scss
>> @import 'settings';
   ^
```

My folder structure is:

```
my-project
    ├─ dist
    ├─ node-modules
        ├─ foundation-sites
        ├─ jquery
        ├─ what-input
        ├─ ...
    ├─ src
        ├─ assets
            ├─ js
            ├─ scss
                ├─ _settings.scss
                ├─ app.scss
```

In app.scss I am importing everything I need:

```
@charset 'utf-8';
@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation';
@import 'motion-ui';
@include foundation-global-styles;
@include foundation-grid;
```

In config.yml I am using the right pahts:

```
PATHS:
...
  # Paths to Sass libraries, which can then be loaded with @import
  sass:
    - "src/assets/scss"
    - "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss"
    - "node_modules/motion-ui/src"
```

Any help?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put `@import 'settings'` after `@import 'foundation'`?, actually as the last import on the list?